# Setting default value equal to parent's value

Tags: mysql

I have a table of categories.  Each category has a parent category (other than the root category) and a color.  I currently have parent set as a FK referring to the key of the same table.

Is there a way to set default color equal to the parent's color?  I've tried setting it up as an after insert trigger or a default constraint, but I'm having issues with self reference in the query itself.  I have a feeling I'm just not 100% understanding how to do it as an inner join.

Comment: Provide sample data and your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

"Redundant" information is a no-no in 'proper' schema design.  The "right" way to solve your problem is to leave `NULL` in the child and reach for the parent's color in the `SELECTs`.  (See the `COALESCE` function and `LEFT JOIN` to avoid stumbling in the root category.)